# Angular : Textfield with suggestion for ajax call response

Tags: angular, angular8, textfield

I need to create a text field with suggestion, I found one of the example of it but it is with static data

```
 <input list="users" name="users">
      <datalist id="users">
        <option value="Alice">
        <option value="Bob">
        <option value="Chuck">
        <option value="Chris">
        <option value="Duke">
        <option value="Emily">
      </datalist>
```

say from service, I am getting all the above value in "userList" variable.

then how can i assign this value in angular to this input tag

Comment: Do you need autocomplete? if yes  here an example with reactive form 
https://netbasal.com/advanced-angular-implementing-a-reusable-autocomplete-component-9908c2f04f5
if you dont need autocomplete just execute call oninInit store the result in a variable the values and use *ngFor like this <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using ngFor directive.

```
<input list="users" name="users">
      <datalist id="users">
        <option *ngFor="let user of userList" [value]="user">
      </datalist>
```